# Numpy sum over all dimension of the outer product

Tags: numpy

If I want to implement this function:
[image]

I know I can write a loop like this:

```
result = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        result += x[i] * y[j]
```

But what if I want to use numpy to complete, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('i,j->',x,y)
```

Or simply sum-reduce and then get product of the scalars -

```
x.sum()*y.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting for this

```
np.sum(x * y[:, None])
```